# Why did $id disappear after the EOF

Tags: shell-script, variable, here-document

```
cat >run_pos2bed3.sh <<EOF
ls 2*/peaks.txt | while read id;
do echo $id done;
EOF
```

after input it

nano only show

```
ls 2*/peaks.txt | while read id;
do echo  done;
EOF
```

How can I add `$id` after `EOF`?

Comment: Considering what you're *putting* in that script, you should also read [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/135943) and [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 3):

> Why did `$id` disappear after the `EOF`?

Because, when you say `<<` and then `$`, you get the value that the variable already has. 
If you do

```
id=foo
cat >run_pos2bed3.sh <<EOF
ls 2*/peaks.txt | while read id;
do echo $id done;
EOF
```

you'll see that you get `do echo foo done`.

> How can I add `$id` after `EOF`?

Do

```
cat >run_pos2bed3.sh << \EOF
ls 2*/peaks.txt | while read id;
do echo $id done;
EOF
```

The difference is the `\` before the `EOF` on the `<<` line.

Comment: You can also use quotes: `<< 'EOF'`.  All documented at https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents

Answer (score 0):

The contents of a here-document will undergo expansion (of variables and command substitutions) unless the document is quoted.  In your case, the here-document is unquoted, so `$id` is expanded.  It is likely that the variable was unset when the document was redirected, so its value is expanded to an empty string.  This makes it appear as if the variable "disappeared".

Instead:

```
cat >run_pos2bed3.sh <<'END_SCRIPT'
ls 2*/peaks.txt |
while read id; do
    echo "$id"
done
END_SCRIPT
```

or, for a safer script (the `id` variable is actually not needed),

```
cat >run_pos2bed3.sh <<'END_SCRIPT'
printf '%s\n' 2*/peaks.txt
END_SCRIPT
```

It's the single quotes in `'END_SCRIPT'` that makes the here-document quoted (this could also be written as either `"END_SCRIPT"` or `\END_SCRIPT`).

I've also quoted the expansion of `$id` within the document itself, as is required by good shell scripting practices (see e.g. [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)).